# Localized list views in SharePoint-hosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, list-view, sharepoint-hosted-app, localization, resource-files

I was trying to localize my SharePoint app and I encountered a bit of a problem. I created a feature resx file, added all the names to it and replaced my static names with $Resources:[MY_LOCALIZED_STRING]. And it works fine except for list views. SharePoint can't resolve display names of all the views.

Has anyone encountered such a problem in the past? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by setting the view names to something like "{View1}","{View2}" etc. and changed them to proper, localized names using CSOM on first app launch.